# Como realizar un join con el modelo user que trae laravel por defecto y un modelo relacionado a este?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

En la migración cree una tabla  llamado empleados, y este tiene el fk de la tabla users que tiene por defecto laravel para el logeo.

Por lo tanto la tabla users y empleados están relacionados, ahora lo que pretendo es  obtener los datos del empleado desde el controlador LoginController, este controlador ya lo trae laravel. Aqui cree un metodo para la autentifacion que es el siguiente:

```
  public function login(){
    $credenciales = $this->validate(request(),[
      'email'=>'required|string',
      'password'=>'required|string'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($credenciales)) {
      $user = Auth::user();          
      if($user->rol == 'admin'){
        return redirect()->route('/gestion-administrador');
      }else if($user->rol == 'supervisor'){
        return redirect('/listado-de-productos');
      }
    }
    return back()->withErrors(['email'=>'correo no valido','password'=>'contraseña incorrecta']);
  }
```

Ahora bien quiero mostrar el nombre del empleado que se logeo en la vista, por lo tanto los datos del empleado están en la tabla empleados. Estoy de acuerdo que si quiero mostrar los datos de la tabla user solo haria esto:

```
<h4>Bienvenido . {{ auth()->user()->name }} </h4>
```

Mi duda es como visualizar los datos del empleado? ya que user y empleados estan relacionados.

Teniendo en cuenta que en mi migracion en la tabla empleados tengo esto:

```
Schema::create('empleados', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('idEmpleado');
            $table->string('nombre',50);
            $table->string('apPaterno',50);
            $table->string('apMaterno',50);
            $table->string('puesto',50);
            $table->integer('departamento_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('departamento_id')
             ->references('idDepartamento')->on('departamentos');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

Tabla user tengo esto:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('rol');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes crear el modelo Empleado en App, puedes usar el comando

**php artisan make:model Empleado**

Crea la relación en el modelo de User de la siguiente forma

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the empleado record associated with the user.
     */
    public function empleado()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Empleado');
    }
}
```

Ahora puedes llamar los datos del empleado de la siguiente forma

```
$empleado = User::find(1)->empleado->nombre;
```

Suponiendo que lo que intentas realizar es una relación One To One te recomiendo veas la documentación de Laravel acá https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one